# Any idea on how to open a batch or application if it is not already opened? (reading from task manager)

Tags: c#, batch-file, console

I'm trying to code a simple console app intended to reopen another app if such closes or crashes. It worked when I tried it on win 7 but then when run it on win 10 it never finds the app or opens lots of consoles.
The apps are cryptocurrency miners, one is coded for AMD (the one that works) the other for nvidia (this one doesn't) I point that out in case the problem has anything to do with how the application was written or some particular thing I may not know about.
I'm new to coding so there are things I still don't know.

this is what I've tried so far:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Resetapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
        {
            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name)) return true;
                   return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true) if (!IsProcessOpen("batch file"))
                           Process.Start("path to batch file");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how the code is executed without brackets, but I would assume that IsProcessOpen should look like this:

```
static public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
{
  foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
  {
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name)) 
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Else the method only looks at the first item in the process list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how i forgot that and why VS didn't report any error when I did.
I will try it out and let you know if it worked!

Comment: UPDATE 11/21 :

I tried adding the brackets but nothing changed. When debugging I noticed how the batch is not recognized as two things happen :

1_the app is not opened
2_ a loop is caused and the a cmd is opened indefinetely (but not the batch I want)

The AMD miner on win 7 still works perfectly, so I don't know if there's a coding issue with the one I want to get to work or what...but it is not being recognized as a running app

Comment: Does starting the batch file without any loops work?

Comment: never tried it, I will do it with the one I know it works (that'd be Claymore batch) and let you know :)
The loop is there so that the program always run and IF the batch crashes the console app get it back to work